# Flutter InAppWebView : loadFile doesn't accept Query Parameters with URL

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-inappwebview

I am implementing [InAppWebView](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/get-started/installation/) in my Flutter Project. I am loading local files from assets which contains all Javascripts and CSS files.

**Expected behavior:** I want to pass query parameters with local file path. For example, `assets/board/index.html?letter=5&mode=1`

**Current behavior:** Like, currently I am passing `assets/board/index.html` and Its loading file successfully. but Its not working If I pass as above path (`assets/board/index.html?letter=5&mode=1`). I am not getting any error but its just showing blank white page.

P.S. It is working for same URL if I host somewhere and use `initialUrlRequest`.

For more detail, check [here](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/1029#issue-1049550817).

Do let me know if any other information you need. Kindly help.

Comment: Are you passing the path as a URI?

Comment: Nope, I am passing as text in `initialFile: "assets/board/index.html?letter=5&mode=1",` @Mudassir